# Specifying package dependencies in electron-installer-snap

Tags: linux, electron, snapcraft

I can successfully build a snap package for my electron app using [electron-installer-snap](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-installer-snap), however, my app depends on the [keytar module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keytar) which subsequently depends on `libsecret-1-0` being installed.

I see no way to pass package dependencies to electron-installer-snap (from their [API](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-installer-snap/blob/master/docs/api.md) doc at least). Currently, I am using the following to create the snap

```
createSnapPackage({
  name: 'my-app',
  executableName: 'myApp',
  arch: 'x64',
  grade: 'devel',
  confinement: 'devmode',
  version: '0.1.0',
  src: '/path-to-src',
  dest: '/path-to-write-snap',
  features: {
    passwords: true
  }
});
```

Note: package creation and install work correctly, however, on launch,the app crashes with the following error:

> A JavaScript error occurred in the main process Uncaught Exception:
>   Error: Cannot open
>   /snap/my-app/x1/my-app/resources/app.asar/keytar.node: Error:
>   libsecret-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

Note: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 to create snaps. Appreciate any help / pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the following user options seems to do the trick:

```
{
  ...
  parts: {
    electronApp: {
      'stage-packages': ['libsecret-1-0'],
    }
  }
}
```